# Netbeans. How to make Content Jpanel width still in accordance with the shape of the parent?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I have a dashboard and Content JPanel page to display a list of data, Content data list will be displayed in the Content dashboard. but sometimes sometimes components like buttons and others move out of the dashboard window if the text value on the data list exceeds the Content Dashboard size.

display example:
**dashboard.java**

```
 _______________________________________________________
|       |                                               |   
|       |                     Dashboard                 |    
|_______|_______________________________________________|
| menu  |                   Content                     |   
|       |                   -------                     | 
|       |                                               |  
|       |                                               |
|       |                                               |
|       |                                               |
|       |                                               |
|       |                                               | 
|       |                                               |
|       |                                               |
|_______|_______________________________________________|
```

content JPanel daftar data = **DataList.Java**:

```
_______________________________________________
|                content                       |          
|                       -------                |             
| __________    _____________   _____________  |     
|| txtField |  |   Button 1  | |   Button 2  | | 
||__________|  |_____________| |_____________| |     
|                                              |   
|                                              |   
| -list data --------------------------------  |  
||                                           | | 
||                                           | |
||                                           | |
||                                           | |
||                                           | | 
||                                           | |
||___________________________________________| |
|______________________________________________|
```

**when the program is run:**

**the view I want :**

```
     _______________________________________________________
    |       |                                               |   
    |       |                     Dashboard                 |    
    |_______|_______________________________________________|
    | menu  |                   content                     |   
    |       |                   -------                     |   
    |       |  __________    _____________   _____________  |      
    |       | | txtField |  |   Button 1  | |   Button 2  | |       
    |       | |__________|  |_____________| |_____________| |     
    |       |                                               |      
    |       |                                               |   
    |       |    -list data ------------------------------  |  
    |       |    |                                        | |
    |       |    |                                        | |
    |       |    |                                        | |
    |       |    |                                        | |
    |       |    |                                        | | 
    |       |    |                                        | |
    |       |    |________________________________________| |
    |_______|_______________________________________________|
```

**display error which is my problem:**

```
 _______________________________________________________
|       |                                               |   
|       |                     Dashboard                 |    
|_______|_______________________________________________|
| menu  |                   content                     |                                                      
|       |                   -------                     |                                       
|       |        __________    _____________   _________|___                                                                      
|       |       | txtField |  |   Button 1  | |   Button 2  |           
|       |       |__________|  |_____________| |_____________|                        
|       |                                               |                                                   
|       |                                               |                                                          
|       |    -list data --------------------------------|-------                                  
|       |    |                                          |       |
|       |    | text value 1-----------------------------|-------|                       
|       |    | text value 2-----------------------------|-------|                           
|       |    |                                          |       |
|       |    |                                          |       |
|       |    |                                          |       |
|       |    |__________________________________________|_______|
|_______|_______________________________________________|
```

I am beginner in building a desktop program and using netbeans. please give me help step by step, if necessary give me a referral like tutorial. any help will be expected.

Comment: [How to use scroll panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: The outcome of your code is highly depend on the `Layout` you used for different parts of your application. Without your code no one can help you with that. Also you will find @MadProgrammer a superman in Swing and you should consider his comments as huge helps.

Comment: For better help don't describe your code but post [mcve]  of it

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, wizards and GUI builders are great if you fully understand the code that they generate, but for beginners I suggest writing the code yourself without the aid of a GUI builder.

When I write a swing application, I start with the top-level window - which is usually `JFrame` and after adding one component to it, I compile my code and run it so I can see if it looks right. This is a cycle of

1. Add swing component to my GUI
2. Compile
3. Run

I learned swing programming from the book *Core JFC* by Kim Topely and I highly recommend it.